# Facebook graph api how to upload a large event picture

Tags: facebook, events, facebook-graph-api, upload, image

I'm uploading images to events using PHP SDK with:

```php
           if ($filename = uploadimage('picture')) // returns full server path to picture
           {
              $facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);

              $eventinfo = array(
                  'picture' => '@' . $filename,
                  'access_token' => $access_token);

              $result = $facebook->api('/' . $event_id . '/', 'post', $eventinfo);
           } `
```

However that only creates a thumbnail image, how can you set the image to the main large event picture?